# Amazon S3 to Ec2 Data Charges

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have amazon Ec2 instance running and also S3 subscription. I have data stored at S3 and the EC2 instance has hosting a site, the the contents from S3 are being displayed on HTML pages, that can be accessed by registered users.

[Amazon S3 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) shows that there are no charges of data transfer from S3 to Ec2. so does this applies in my case?

Comment: Do the users make requests to s3 directly? Seems to me like either the users access s3 directly (and so you pay s3 data charges) or they access it via your ec2 instance, so no s3->ec2 data transfer charges but increased ec2 data charges

Comment: They Do not access directly, They access the website running on EC2 Instance.

Comment: But does (for example) the html page serverd by the instance have images who src is pointing at s3 ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes html page's images source is pointing to s3.

Comment: Then you will incur s3 data charges, since users will download images straight from s3